# Need help with this series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{{\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor}} \over n}$$

I am almost certain that the series converges and I tried using the Cauchy convervence condition with no success. 
That $\sqrt{k}$ should be inside a floor function but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you know about Dirichlet test for convergence?

Comment: I just read about it, but I don't see how to use it in this particular case

Comment: The biggest problem with your MathJax was that you used forward slashes(/) instead of backslashes(\)

Comment: Dirichlet's test seems not to apply here.

Comment: I ruined it again, for some reason the fraction command is not working

Comment: @Greg Martin Yes, I also noticed it now. Not sure if the sequence of partial sums of $(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}$ is bounded.

Comment: @Mark: you can work out the exact values of the partial sums up to perfect squares, and those exact values are not bounded. Edited to add: well, the question keeps changing, so it's hard to say....

Comment: @Greg Martin Can you elaborate a bit more please? I tried looking at the sum from n=k^2 to (k+1)^2 -1 because on those intervals the floor of rooth n is the same, but I didnt get too far with that idea

Comment: The current version of the question makes no sense: $n$ is being used both as a summation variable and a denominator outside the sum.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to fix it, the n should be dividing inside the summation but the frac  command is giving me some trouble.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Pack together the terms between two perfect squares. You get an alternating series, whose general term is something like
$$(-1)^k \sum_{n= k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1} \frac{1}{n}$$

Now use Leibniz test to show that it converges.

Comment: Just one question, is it correct to group terms like that without knowing it is absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The sign remains constant between two successive perfect squares, and the sum can be written as

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(H_{(2k+1)^2-1}-H_{(2k)^2-1}-H_{(2k)^2-1}+H_{(2k-1)^2-1}\right)$$ where $H_i$ denotes an harmonic number.

Using the asymptotic expression, the general term is of order

$$\log\frac{((2k+1)^2-1)((2k-1)^2-1)}{((2k)^2-1)^2}=\frac1{2k^2}+o(k^{-2})$$ and this converges.

The convergence of the initial series is guaranteed by the fact that the partial sums do not differ from the partial "compressed" sum by more than $\dfrac1k$ (the difference between harmonic numbers with perfect square indexes).